# Div does not get the full width of the page

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Data Retrieve</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <style>
        #demo{
          background-color:purple;
          color: white;
          width: 100%;
        }
        #home{
          width: 45px;
        }
        #back{
          width: 25px;
        }
        #header{
          width:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <table id="info_table" class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="header">
                            <p align="center"><span style="float: left"><a href="http://localhost/directory/BangladeshDirectory.html"><img src="back.png" id="back"></a></span><b>মন্ত্রণালয়</b><span style="float: right"><a href="http://localhost/directory/BangladeshDirectory.html"><img src="home.png" id="home"></a></span><span style="float: right"><a href="http://localhost/directory/montronaloy.html"><img src="refresh.png" id="refresh"></a></span></p>
                        </td>   
                   </tr>
                   <tr>  
                        <td id="demo" align="center"><td>
                   </tr>
                </table> 
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</body>
</html>  
<script>
    var bn_num = new Array('০','১','২','৩','৪','৫','৬','৭','৮','৯');

    function bn_num_convert(num){
        //console.log(num.length);
        var bn_val = '';
        for(i=0;i<num.length;i++){
          //console.log(num[i] + '/' + bn_num[num[i]]);
          bn_val = bn_val + bn_num[num[i]];
        }
        //console.log(bn_val);
        return bn_val;
    }
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/directory/ministri.json",function(obj){
        var info ='';
        //alert(obj.data.length);
        var count = obj.data.length;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ='মোট মন্ত্রণালয় ('+bn_num_convert(count.toString())+')';
        var count = obj.data.length;
        $.each(obj.data,function(key,value){

            info += '<tr>';
            info +='<td><a href="http://localhost/directory/show.php?id='+value.id+'" style="text-decoration:none">'+value.sitename_bn+'<span style="float: right"> > </span>'+ '</a></td>';
            info += '</tr>';
[This is the corresponding output of the code.][1]
        });

           $('#info_table').append(info);
    });
</script>
```

Firstly here purple background color doesn't get the full wide.if i inspect the background there shows an empty td which cause the problem.if i delete the empty td then i get perfect result.but there is no empty td in my code.plz see the code and show me the error.
Secondly there is no horizontal line at the end of the output result.why last line doesn't get horizontal line?

Comment: can you please share a fiddle, that will be better to look into problem

Comment: Why did you reject the edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not closing the td, thats why empty td is appending.

```
 <td id="demo" align="center"></td>
```

Close the td like in above code

and remove margin and padding as other posts suggested in case if you want full width till ends.

Comment: It happens sometimes while coding. Happy Coding!

Comment: there is another problem at end of the last value i don't get the horizontal line.can you plz see the code again.

Answer (score 0):

Set body margin paddding to 0px

```
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: That should help. You are using bootstrap and it automatically adds padding.

Comment: @DomenikReitzner is right bootstrap also getting some auto width.. So if you want to make it full width than make the body margin 0 and put that div before <div class="container-fluid"> . than it will get will width :)

Comment: i already do that.but the problem is not solved.i can identify the problem but can't solve in my code.problem is when i inspect the output there shows an empty td tag.if i delete that then the output is perfect.but problem is that in my code there is no empty td tag.therefore i can't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `&nbsp;` in demo id  td, it will show.

`See this`https://jsfiddle.net/v6mwpz89/3/

Cheers!